# AWS Serverless CSV to Queue to CSV Architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm currently playing around with AWS for some serverless CSV processing. Decent familiarity with EC2 and Dynamo. I'm sure there is a better way to structure this, and I've not found an efficient way to store the data. Any architecture suggestions would be much appreciated.

This flow will take in a CSV uploaded to S3, process all the rows of tuples and output a new CSV of processed data to S3.

What's the 1) optimal architecture and 2) optimal place to store the data before the queue is complete until the CSV can be built

Data flow and service architecture:

CSV (contains tuples) (S3) -> CSV processing (Lambda) -> Queue (SNS) -> Queue Processing (Lambda) -> ????? temporary storage for queue items that have been processed before they get written to CSV ???? (what to use here?) -> CSV building (Lambda) -> CSV storage (S3)

Clever ideas appreciated.

Comment: Do the rows have any relation in terms of order?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are over complicating matters

s3 can trigger invoke a lambda function when events occur.  This is directly set up in the s3 buckets event notifications

So use this to make a converted version of the CSV in another bucket

Amazon have an example of how to do this sort of thing here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Comment: Thanks, I am using the S3 trigger. However, if I load 50000 tuples in a csv into lambda, processing takes too long. It can be done item by item in parallel (which would be more efficient). S3 is triggering the lambda function to process the CSV. The Lambda function then feeds the queue so it doesn't 1) hang for over the 3 min time limit of Lambda and 2) to ensure more efficient processing.

Comment: Right, if the data processing is likely to take longer than the lambda can run for it will need a more complicated processing structure.  The time limit is 5 minutes btw (300 seconds) not 3 minutes, don't know if that helps

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to fix/come up with? =)

Answer (score 1):

*Update (reply to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731951/aws-serverless-csv-to-queue-to-csv-architecture#comment80414035_46733650)):*

> it doesn't parallelize anything

You can divide the task equally if you have a good idea of how many tuples can be processed by a single Lambda within its time limit.

For example, given the following info...

- original CSV contains 50,000 tuples
- a single Lambda can process 5000 tuples within the time limit.

You can then do 10 parallel asynchronous invocations of the *processor* Lambda with each of them working with a different `offset`.

---

*Original answer:*

You can make it work with two Lambdas:

1. *Listener*

   - S3-triggered Lambda whose only job is to pass the s3 path of the new uploaded CSV to the *Processor* Lambda.
2. *Processor*

   - a Lambda that is triggered by the *Listener*. It will require the `s3 path` and the `offset` as parameters (where `offset` is the row of the CSV that it should start processing.
   - This Lambda performs the actual processing of your CSV rows. It should keep track of which row it's currently processing and just before the Lambda time limit is reached, it will stop and invoke itself with the same `s3 path` but with a new `offset`.

So, basically, it's a recursive Lambda that invokes itself until all CSV rows are processed.

To check for the remaining time, you can use the `context.getRemainingTimeInMillis()` method (NodeJS) in a `while` or `for` loop in your handler.

Comment: Thanks! That's an interesting solution. Using a temp file in S3 to keep the position of the 'queue' makes sense. I think it accomplishes 1) "hang for over the 3 min time limit of Lambda", but not "2) to ensure more efficient processing" as it doesn't parallelize anything. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Shanks That's a good exercise for you. How do you parallelize it?